# need help in Converting my angular 2 component to npm library

Tags: angular, npm

I have created an component in angular2, now I need to convert the components to npm library so that it can be installed via

> npm install

I have installed angular CLI for creating the component, I have searched web I can't able to find a clear-cut instructions in converting the components to npm library, please guide me to the process of achieving it

Comment: I had to do the same thing and I have to warn you, it's a complicated task. I tried to adapt the `ng-bootstrap` architecture to my project and with some customization i was able to get it working: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Unfortunately this is a way to broad question and doesn't belong to stackoverflow.

Comment: can you say me how you achieved it am totally not having idea how to convert it to npm library

Comment: This would take me multiple hours to write down. Try to take a look at the gulpfile in ng-bootstrap, try to analyse what exactly is going on and then start to port it to your own lib. NOTE: ngc, umd and npm are the most important tasks

Comment: yeah I'll look into it, it will better if you answer this question in detail (you may take your own time not a problem)

Answer (score 2):

1 . Read the NPM publishing documentation here:  https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers

2 . Create your app as normal angular application (even using angular cli) then in your `package.json` file create a files entry  containing only the files or directories that you want users to install with npm. (that should exclude your main angular module and only export component, services, directives e.t.c)

```
 "files": [
        "README.md",
        "index.js",
        "index.ts",
        "src/app/component-folder/*"
    ],
```

3 . In your `package.json` again create a main key with your entry file (entry file should export you functions, take care not to exclude the .js version from version control.

```
"main": "index.js"
```

3 .1 Sample entry .ts file

```
export * from './src/app/component-name/component.module';
export * from './src/app/component-name/app.component';
export * from './src/app/component-name/app.service';
```

You can test before publishing to npm by creating a tar file and npm installing to your other app

Comment: An example repo to refer to https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker. note that the files key in package.json is for whitelisting only necessary files for npm. There are other ways to do it - just go through the documentation